# Suppressing (Hiding) data when exporting in Crystal Reports 2011

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using the Crystal Reports 2011 designer just to test it out. I need to be able to hide certain components, e.g. a sub-report, when exporting to different formats like Excel or .pdf. I'm guessing this can be achieved through the Suppress field with a formula, but I can't find the right syntax. Needs to be something like this:

```
If ExportFormat="Excel" then Suppress
Else if ExportFormat="PDF" then Show
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem like there is a variable to represent the ExportFormat type when using expressions in Crystal Reports.

It is possible to overcome this problem by setting a parameter programmatically during an export event i.e. create a parameter @ExportFormat and during the export event set this parameter depending on the type of export e.g. if the export taking place is to Excel, set @ExportFormat="Excel". Then the following expression can be used to suppress a control:

```
{?@ExportFormat}='Excel'
```

Answer (score 1):

You got it almost completely right:

```
If ExportFormat='Excel' then TRUE
Else if ExportFormat='PDF' then FALSE
```

This formula goes into the suppress formula. (You need to click this small button with the "x-2" and pencil on it...)

Comment: the problem is that the variable name 'ExportFormat' is incorrect, and I can't find the proper variable name. thanks.

Comment: Search it in the small window with the report fields (It's in the formula screen, the left one of the three windows at the top). Browse through it and double click the field once you've found it. It will copy it correctly to the lower part, where you type the rest of the formula.

Comment: @Urik can you attach a screen shot of it i also need this.

Comment: Readying through again your question and comment, I might got something wrong. I don't think there's an inner variable for that in CR. I thought that "ExportFormat" is a variable that comes from your code.